# Is possible creating only 1 file .exe for a Maui project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, maui

Currently, to access my Maui .NET code, I have to navigate to bin/Release/windows/etc.../Service.exe, but to get to this, there are many other files around. Is there an option for users to open this application as a only 1 .exe file where they don't see all the other files, instead of what I'm currently doing?